# How to send HTTP requests from KrakenD to RabbitMQ and create queues dynamically

Tags: rabbitmq, krakend

I am using KrakenD as an API gateway and I want to send input HTTP requests from KrakenD to a RabbitMQ server. I want to get the name of the queue from the request header and create the queue if it does not exist. I am using the AMQP producer component of KrakenD to connect to RabbitMQ.

I have the following configuration for my KrakenD endpoint:

```json
{
    "endpoint": "/produce",
    "method": "POST",
    "backend": [
        {
            "host": [
                "amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672"
            ],
            "disable_host_sanitize": true,
            "extra_config": {
                "backend/amqp/producer": {
                    "name": "{{.Headers.queue}}",
                    "exchange": "some-exchange",
                    "durable": true,
                    "delete": false,
                    "no_wait": true,
                    "routing_key": [
                        "#"
                    ],
                    "auto_delete": false,
                    "exclusive": false,
                    "backoff_strategy": "exponential-jitter"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am sending a POST request to the /produce endpoint with a header queue: test-queue and a JSON body {"message": "Hello world"}. I expect KrakenD to send the message to the test-queue in RabbitMQ and create the queue if it does not exist.

It seems that KrakenD is not creating the exchange or the queue for me. How can I fix this? Do I need to create the exchange and the queue manually before sending the request? Is there a way to make KrakenD create them dynamically?

Comment: It does appear that they need to be created prior...